# upper-band of the Integral expression

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

Consider below integral expression

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}g(y)[\int_{a}^{\infty}(1-e^{-(k+y)x})f(x)dx ]dy \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Where, we know:
$$f(x)>0\ ,\ \ a\leq x \leq \infty$$
$$\ k>0$$
$$g(y)>0\ ,\ \ 0\leq y \leq \infty$$

I need to show $(1)$ has an upper-band as:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}g(y)[\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx ]dy \ \ \ \ (2)$$

---

**My Analysis:**

I think since $f(x)$ is always positive,we can consider it as a density function. Also, since $e^{-(k+y)x}$ is strictly decreasing with respect to both $x$ and $y$, we can say average value of the $(1-e^{-(k+y)x})$ under density function of $f(x)$ is lower than the case setting the exponential term to zero. i.e., $e^{-(k+y)x}:=0$.

---

**Question:**

If I am right, how can I prove my physical analysis mathematically? ($(1) \leq (2)$):

Any hint, guidance, and comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Your analysis seems not quite correct.  A more straightforward approach would be to observe that $e^{-(k+y)x} > 0$, so $1- e^{-(k+y)x} < 1$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas so, thus the inequality holds. Am I right about the inequality relation between (1) and (2) ?

Comment: Yes, indeed you are.